# disabling facebook comments with actions field on wall posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-comments

My app allows users to interact with each other for a unique purpose. As part of this experience I post on user's wall so his/her friends can know about the post from user and they can come to app for interaction. But in this case, users may just end up commenting on the facebook page itself and my app will not have any knowledge of this interaction. To avoid this, I am wondering if I can disable comments on this post. Graph API documentations states that I can use the "actions" field on wall post for such purpose. I tried that with various combinations of Comment and empty link or link that takes the user to my app etc. But I notice that no matter what I set, facebook always shows link to the wall post instead of what I tried to put.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this purpose?
Thanks.

Comment: _“Graph API documentations states that I can use the "actions" field on wall post for such purpose.”_ – where would that be?

Comment: developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post

This page has a table that talks about actions field. actions - A list of available actions on the post (including commenting, liking, and an optional app-specified action) - Requires access_token array of objects containing the name and link

Comment: Yes, this property includes the default actions – but that does not mean that you are able to suppress them by specifying your own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling Facebook comments](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6820576/disabling-facebook-comments)